# Show Active storage validation errors with form errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using `rails 5.2`, `bootstrap-4`, `bootstrap_form` with `active-storage` file is uploading successfully. What I want is when I enter company name in form then it should check for `company_logo`.

I tried with this it is working good when I include error loop in form
Here in view

```
- if @company.errors.any?
  #error_explanation
    %ul
      - @company.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
        %li= message
```

Model Code

```
has_one_attached :company_logo
validates :name, :company_logo,presence: true
after_validation :is_logo?, if: Proc.new { |a| a.name? }


def is_logo?
      errors.add(:base, 'Please upload your company logo.') if !self.company_logo.attached?
end
```

I want this kind of validation with file field
[image: I want this kind of validation with file field]

Comment: Add presence: true to your validates :name, :company_logo line.

Comment: @hashrocket It is already there I forgot to add in question now I updated , It is not working

Answer (score 3):

Actually active_storage doesn't support validation.

What i did for presence :

```
  class CompanyModel < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :company_logo

    validate :company_logo?

    private

    def company_logo?
      errors.add(:base, 'Please upload your company logo.') unless company_logo.attached?
    end
  end
```

But this will upload the file to your storage and create an active_storage blob field in database...

The only workarround i found to delete file on storage and database field (so ugly):

```
def company_logo?
  # Clean exit if there is a logo
  return if company_logo.attached?

  # Unless add error
  errors.add(:base, 'Please upload your company logo.')

  # Purge the blob
  company_logo.record.company_logo_attachment.blob.purge

  # Purge attachment
  company_logo.purge
end
```

Comment: when there is validation for another field and file is in `file_field`, like you said file is uploaded and create an `active_storage` blob field in database so is there any way to insert into another table `active_record_attachments` so file is uploaded it doesn't depend on other form error because if there is validation in form user have to upload file another time that is not correct

Answer (score 1):

A nice solution is the [active_storage_validations](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations) gem. Add to your Gemfile, then `bundle install`:

```rb
# Gemfile
gem 'active_storage_validations'
```

Inside your model, try something like this for a video attachment:

```rb
has_one_attached :video

validates :video,
size: { less_than: 50.megabytes, 
  message: 'Video size cannot be larger than 50 megabytes.' },
content_type: 
{ in: %w(video/mov video/quicktime video/mp4 video/avi video/mpeg), 
  message: 'Upload must be a valid video type' }
```

#### References

- The [readme](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/active_storage_validations#usage) has many very useful examples.
- This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48158770/5783745) and answers has some relevant information too.