# Validate file type on Direct Uploads with Active Storage? Is it possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activestorage

I created a method in my model to validate the upload file type.  But it won't work, and I assume it's because i am using Direct uploads.

Is it possible to validate the file type with direct uploads with active storage? and How can I?

**I tried:**

**Model:**

```
validate :correct_video_type


  def correct_video_type
    if video.attached? && video.content_type.in?(%w(video/mov video/mp4 video/avi video/mpeg))
      errors.add(:video, "Must be video format")
    elsif video.attached? == false
      errors.add(:video, "Video must be attached")
    end
  end
```

**View:**

```
<%= form.file_field :video, class: "upload", direct_upload: true %>
```

And nothing becomes validated...

**I also tried front end validation, but this didn't work:**

```
 <%= form.file_field :video, class: "upload", direct_upload: true, accept: 'video/mov, video/mpeg, video/mp4, video/avi' %>
```

None of these worked.  Even if the front-end were to work, i would still want to validate it further on the backend.

How can I validate this?

Comment: Did you try adding a breakpoint in `correct_video_type` to see if it's called?

Comment: I haven't.  I also attempted this without using direct_upload and it also didn't work.  I can assume its not being called?

Comment: i would say try the breakpoint to chec

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158770/activestorage-file-attachment-validation

Comment: @Nandhini Thanks i guess it 's time to upgrade....

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [gem](https://github.com/aki77/activestorage-validator). As I know It implements what you did)